# groovy is not finding annotated tests

Tags: groovy, junit

Still new to Groovy and trying to figure out unit testing.  I'm trying to use the Junit4 style of testing.

```
import org.junit.Test
import junit.framework.*
import junit.textui.TestRunner

class DegenerateTestCase {
    @Test
    void testAlwaysTrue() {
        assert true
    }

    @Test
    void someMethodName() {
        assert true
    }
}

TestRunner.run(DegenerateTestCase)
```

But when I run the script, I get

> There was 1 failure:
>
> 1. warning(junit.framework.TestSuite$1)junit.framework.AssertionFailedError:> No tests found in DegenerateTestCase

This has to be something simple that I'm missing.

Comment: You will get the exact same error if you convert all of that to Java.  The issue isn't a Groovy one.  It is a JUnit one.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers, Oxygen.3a Release (4.7.3a). I have the Groovy plugin downloaded from the marketplace (compiler level 2.5).

I tried running it with junit5 which had only one difference which was instead of having `import org.junit.Test` I had `import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*`. I didnt need `import junit.framework.* or import junit.textui.TestRunner` I just ran it as is and worked fine.

I then switched to Junit4 and did the same but switched `import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*` to `import org.junit.Test` and it works.

my code looks like this:

```
import org.junit.Test
```

class DegenerateTestCase {

```
@Test
void testAlwaysTrue() {
    assert true
}

@Test
void someMethodName() {
    assert true
}
```

}